# TypeError: a is undefined in jquery at the first line?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, typeerror

So, in my code, when I press my #jsonclick button, it activates my script which populates a table with information from a JSON page. The problem I am having is that I am getting a TypeError: a is undefined, and I have no idea why.
Here is my code:

jQuery function

```
   $("#clickjson").click(function () {
    $.getJSON("gmessagegroup.php?gid=" + $('#gbox').val(), function (data) {
        $.each(data.messages, function (key, val) {
            if (data.messages[key].clientmessageid != undefined) {
                console.log(data.messages[key].clientmessageid + ":" + data.messages[key].from + " - " + data.messages[key].content);
                $("#messages tbody tr:last").after('<tr><td>' + data.messages[key].clientmessageid + '</td><td>' + escapeHtml(data.messages[key].from).replace("https://bn1-client-s.gateway.messenger.live.com/v1/users/ME/contacts/8:", "") + '</td><td id=' + data.messages[key].clientmessageid + ' contenteditable="true">' + escapeHtml(data.messages[key].content) + '</td></tr>');
            }
        });
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        var message_status = $("#status");
        $("td[contenteditable=true]").blur(function () {
            var field_userid = $(this).attr("id");
            var value = $(this).text();
            $.post('groupedit.php', field_userid + "=" + value, function (data) {});
        });

    }, 1000);
});
```

The code is getting the value of the selected item in a dropdown select. I tried putting and alert in and it is putting out the correct value that is being pushed out to the PHP. I am unsure of where the TypeError comes into play, all I know is that when I remove ?gid=" + $('#gbox').val() from the end of the php, the error goes away. Problem is, I need that for the php to work. Can somebody please tell me why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: It means an element having `gbox` id is not found in your page, check it.

Comment: <select name="groupchats" id="gbox"> This is the dropdown select. How can it not find this?

Comment: Then make sure `gmessagegroup.php?` is returning valid json.Check in console

Comment: Maybe your select is not ready in the DOM when you execute the ajax function to get json. You can check this: `?gid="+ (($('#box').val()) ? $('#box').val() : 0)` that will return `0 ` if `#box` is not found.

Comment: If I do gmessagegroup.php?gid='valuehere', i get a full page's worth of JSON response. 'valuehere' being a value i manually place there. I get no other errors besides that TypeError

Comment: *"I'm getting TypeError: a is undefined"* There is no `a` identifier in that code.

Comment: @RohanKumar: *"It means an element having gbox id is not found in your page"* What makes you think `TypeError: a is undefined` relates to the `gbox` element not being found? If it's not found, all that will happen is that the URL will be `gmessagegroup.php?gid=undefined`, because if you call `val` on an empty jQuery set, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Well I am not sure why I am getting that error then, because as soon as I remove ?gid = value from the php, there is no error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it is jquery error and I think OP is using minified version, and this type of error comes when any object is undefined or not found by jquery

Comment: <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

Comment: @RohanKumar: No, it doesn't. Try it. jQuery is set-based.

Comment: Those are the scripts I am using, is it a matter of not using jquery.min?

Comment: @AbsoluteZero: Whether you use the minified or unminified version of jQuery doesn't matter.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clearing that up. But that still doesn't help my case, as you havent really provided any sort of positive feedback or help to me or the other commenter which is trying to help as well.

Comment: Show us your php code

Answer (score 1):

Actually in your `json response` messages is not found thats why it is responding as `a is undefined` check if you json data has `messages` or not like,

```
if(data && data.messages.length) // check for messages
   $.each(data.messages, function (key, val) {
        if (data.messages[key].clientmessageid != undefined) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Snapshop

[image]